# Comparing byte[] in android room Daos

Tags: android, arrays, database, sqlite, android-room

in my project, there is a login system in which the username, the email and the password are stored in the sqlite database from by android room. They are all hashed via an android chiper algorithm and then converted by a type converter to String to the database. But I cannot compare them with the following statement it is just going to return null...

So how do I compare those byte[] correctly? Or should it work like that and my mistake is somewhere else?

```java
@Query("select passwordHashed from login where userHashed = :userHashGiven")
byte[] getPasswordHashByUserHash(userHashGiven byte[])
```

My TypeConverter and the Login object looks like this:

```java
@TypeConverter
fun stringToBytes(s: String) : ByteArray {
    return s.toByteArray(EncrypterUtil.charset)
}

@TypeConverter
fun bytesToString(bytes: ByteArray) : String {
    return String(bytes, EncrypterUtil.charset)
}
```

```java
@Entity(tableName = "login")
public class Login {

@NonNull
@PrimaryKey
private byte[] userHashed;

@ColumnInfo
private byte[] emailHashed;

@ColumnInfo
private byte[] passwordHashed;

@ColumnInfo
private int biometric;

public Login(@NotNull byte[] userHashed, byte[] emailHashed, byte[] passwordHashed, int biometric) {
    this.userHashed = userHashed;
    this.emailHashed = emailHashed;
    this.passwordHashed = passwordHashed;
    this.biometric = biometric;
}

@NonNull
public byte[] getUserHashed() {
    return userHashed;
}

public void setUserHashed(@NonNull byte[] userHashed) {
    this.userHashed = userHashed;
}

public byte[] getEmailHashed() {
    return emailHashed;
}

public void setEmailHashed(byte[] emailHashed) {
    this.emailHashed = emailHashed;
}

public byte[] getPasswordHashed() {
    return passwordHashed;
}

public void setPasswordHashed(byte[] passwordHashed) {
    this.passwordHashed = passwordHashed;
}

public int getBiometric() {
    return biometric;
}

public void setBiometric(int biometric) {
    this.biometric = biometric;
}
```

Result in the database is the following:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the **`Login`** class (Entity) that you have shown.

The `@Query` is incorrect in that it is using columns `passwordHash` and `userHash` whilst the Entity has respective columns named `passwordHashed` and `userHashed`.

- Should it instead be `@Query("select passwordHashed from login where userHashed = :userHashGiven")`?
- *As you have a mix of Java and Kotlin, it may be that you have inadvertently mixed up the table that you are extracting the data from with the table that you are inserting data.*

In regard to comparing BLOBs then SQLite uses a memory compare and thus the compare should work. As an example consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS login;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login (userHashed BLOB);
INSERT INTO login VALUES
    (x'B1C1D1E1F1'),
    (x'F1E1D1C1B1'),
    (x'0101010101'),
    (x'FFEEDDCCBB')
;
SELECT userHashed, hex(userHashed) FROM login WHERE userHashed = x'B1C1D1E1F1';
```

This

1. drops the `login` table if it exists,
2. creates the login table (just the one BLOB column),
3. Inserts 4 rows all with different BLOB values, and finally
4. Extracts rows (should be only the one that matches the argument)

Running the above returns the expected result as per :-

[image]

- *Note that Navicat was used for the above and that is how it displays BLOBS and hence why the SQLite hex function has been used to display the value as a string representation and thus to confirm that the expected row has been returned.*

**Example**

Based upon the corrected (Query) code that you have supplied **does work**.

Assuming that the Dao is call AllDao then the following MainActivity was used to test the code.

Note that the following @Query was also added :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE userHashed = :userHashGiven")
    Login[] getLoginsByUserHash(byte[] userHashGiven);
```

- This to extract a Login object rather than a byte[]

The code used is :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Database db;
    AllDao allDao;
    byte[] t1 = new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
        t2 = new byte[]{10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19},
        t3 = new byte[]{20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29},
        t4 = new byte[]{30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39}
    ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(this,Database.class,"mydb")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        allDao = db.allDao();
        Login l1 = new Login(t1,t2,t3,10);
        Login l2 = new Login(t2,t3,t4,20);
        Login l3 = new Login(t3,t4,t1,30);
        Login l4 = new Login(t4,t1,t2,40);
        allDao.insertLogin(l1);
        allDao.insertLogin(l2);
        allDao.insertLogin(l3);
        allDao.insertLogin(l4);
        Login[] extractedLogins = allDao.getLoginsByUserHash(t2);
        Log.d("LOGINTEST","Extracted " + extractedLogins.length +  " rows");
        byte[] passwordHash = allDao.getPasswordHashByUserHash(t2);
        Log.d("LOGINTEST","Extracted " + passwordHash.length +  " rows");
        Log.d("LOGINTEST",passwordHash.toString());
    }
}
```

As you can see, this adds 4 rows to the Login table using some pre-defined byte[]'s as per t1 - t4 (the userHashed being t1-t4 respectively for the 4 rows).

After the data has been inserted an Array of Login's is extracted using the new query which should retrieve just the 1 Login as per the WHERE clause.

Then the original query is used to extract the byte[].

When run in debug mode with a break point one the line `Log.d("LOGINTEST",passwordHash.toString());`

The the following results can be seen.

The Log includes :-

D/LOGINTEST: Extracted 1 rows
D/LOGINTEST: Extracted 10 rows

- i.e. 1 Login object has been extracted by the first(new) query and a byte[] that is 10 bytes in length has been returned by the 2nd(original) query.

The Debug screen shows (as expected):-

[image]

That is `extractedLogins` (an array of `Login` objects) has 1 object and the passwordHashed value is t4 (3rd value of the 2nd row)

and also that the byte[] extracted is t4 (again as expected).

> Or should it work like that and my mistake is somewhere else?

I believe that your issue is elsewhere (as the working example shows you that the query works).

Comment: I am sorry for the wrong query, it was wirtten by me directly into stackOverflow while the rest was copied... It is edited now

Comment: @CaipiDE I've added a working test example showing you query working (albeit it with simplified data)

Comment: I rebuilded the system... Now it works with your help, thank... I still wonder where the error was coming from...